# Relationship: Products, Categories and Subcategories

Tags: laravel-5

I'm new to laravel 5.2.

Would anyone help me out with an example  to define model relationship between categories - subcategories - products and how to fetch products under subcategories by relevant id?

```
    // Category  model
public function subcategories(){ return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory', 'category_id'); }    
public function products() {return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'subcategory_id');}

// Subcategory model 
public function categories() {return $this->belongsTo('Category');}
public function products() {return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Product'
,'App\Category','subcategory_id','category_id','id');}

// Product model
public function categories() {   return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');}
public function subcategories() {return $this->belongsTo('App\Subcategory');}
```

---

```
// my controller
// class to fetch subcategories under category
public function show_subcategory($name){  
$categories=Category::whereName($name)->get(); 
return view('project.show_subcategory')->with('categories',$categories); 
} 

// class to fetch product under subcategories    
public function show_product($id){ 
$subcategories = Subcategory::whereId($id)->get();
return view('project.show_product')->with('subcategories',$subcategories);}
```

---

```
 //  views - show_subcategory.blade.php
@foreach( $categories as $category)
@foreach( $category->subcategories as $subcategory )    
{{$subcategory->name}}
@endforeach
@endforeach 

//  views - show_product.blade.php
@foreach( $subcategories as $subcategory) 
@foreach( $subcategory->products as $product ) 
{{$product->title}}
@endforeach 
@endforeach
```

---

```
Route::get('/show_subcategory/{name}','Project\MainController@show_subcategory');
Route::get('/show_product/{id}','Project\MainController@show_product');
```

---

```
// migrations - create_subcategories_table.php
$table->engine = 'InnoDB';
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
$table->string('image');
$table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade'); 
$table->timestamps();

// migrations - create_products_table.php
$table->engine = 'InnoDB';            
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('subcategory_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('subcategory_id')->references('id')->on('subcategories')->onDelete('cascade'); 
$table->string('title');
$table->text('description');
$table->integer('price');
$table->boolean('availability')->default(1);
$table->string('image');
$table->timestamps();
```

> note : class show_subcategory work well and i can display subcategories under categories
>
> but class show_product  dont work and i can't display products under
>   subcategories .. the view dont show any errors and dont display
>   products
>
> i can't know where is my error in model relation or in controller class or in view

Comment: Would you please advise how the three models are related? What is the relation between Subcategory and Product?

Comment: thanks mina for your edit and replay . please check my answer to more explain relation between models

Comment: i updated, please check

Answer (score 0):

YOUR ERROR:

1. Your tried to get products INTO subcategory table :/ , your subcategory table doen't have products information.
2. You tried to filter subcategories WHERE id =  $id  , this get subcategory information and NOT product information. try to do:

url:

```
/show_product/1
```

blade:

```
@foreach( $subcategories as $subcategory) 

{{$subcategory->name}}

@endforeach
```

it will work and will show subcategory name where subcategory id is 1.

**TO GET PRODUCTS WITH SUBCATEGORY**

you need have a subcategory id into your product table so you can do:

**ROUTE**

```
Route::get('/show_product/{subcategory_id}','Project\MainController@show_product');
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
// get products with a specific subcategory id

public function show_product($subcategory_id){ 
$subcategories = Subcategory::where('subcategory_id', $subcategory_id)->get();
return view('project.show_product', compact('subcategories '));
}
```

With this you will get all products that have a specific id subcategory,

MAYBE YOU DID YOU WANT LIKE THIS:

```
// class to fetch product under subcategories    
public function show_product($id){ 
$subcategories = Subcategory::where('product_id', $id)->get();
return view('project.show_product')->with('subcategories',$subcategories);}
```

This can get all subcategories that have a specific product ID. But you need change the migrations subcategory and ADD product_id relation.

```
// migrations - create_subcategories_table.php
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('image');
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade'); 
    $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade'); 
    $table->timestamps();
```

You need also add relation in your model product and subcategory, but i can not undestand well your structure taxonomy you have. Please make an example:

1. first Category

   - firs subcategory
   - second subcategory
2. second category

   - other subcategories
   - etc.

Each product have a category, and category have more subcategory childrens, but i'm not sure if is that you want.  Do an screenshot may can help us.

Comment: thanks diego for quick replay but  i want to display products under subcategories

Comment: dear diego . i have updated my answer but still get nothing . please check my answer to see model - controller - route updating

Comment: Ok, this this ID: 
public function show_product($id){  
$subcategories = Product::whereId($id) is a specific Id of someone product ??

Comment: dear diego  i updated my answer please check it -- the view don't show error and don't show display products under subcategories

Answer (score 0):

```
// Category  model
public function subcategories(){ return $this->hasMany('App\Subcategory', 'category_id'); }    
public function products() {return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'subcategory_id');}

// Subcategory model 
public function categories() {return $this->belongsTo('Category');}
public function products() {return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Product'
,'App\Category','subcategory_id','category_id','id');}

// Product model
public function categories() {   return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');}
public function subcategories() {return $this->belongsTo('App\Subcategory');}
```

---

```
// my controller
// class to fetch subcategories under category
public function show_subcategory($name){  
$categories=Category::whereName($name)->get(); 
return view('project.show_subcategory')->with('categories',$categories); 
} 

// class to fetch product under subcategories    
public function show_product($id){ 
$subcategories = Subcategory::whereId($id)->get();
return view('project.show_product')->with('subcategories',$subcategories);}
```

---

```
 //  views - show_subcategory.blade.php
@foreach( $categories as $category)
@foreach( $category->subcategories as $subcategory )    
{{$subcategory->name}}
@endforeach
@endforeach 

//  views - show_product.blade.php
@foreach( $subcategories as $subcategory) 
@foreach( $subcategory->products as $product ) 
{{$product->title}}
@endforeach 
@endforeach
```

---

```
Route::get('/show_subcategory/{name}','Project\MainController@show_subcategory');
Route::get('/show_product/{id}','Project\MainController@show_product');
```

---

```
// migrations - create_subcategories_table.php
$table->engine = 'InnoDB';
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
$table->string('image');
$table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade'); 
$table->timestamps();

// migrations - create_products_table.php
$table->engine = 'InnoDB';            
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('subcategory_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('subcategory_id')->references('id')->on('subcategories')->onDelete('cascade'); 
$table->string('title');
$table->text('description');
$table->integer('price');
$table->boolean('availability')->default(1);
$table->string('image');
$table->timestamps();
```

> note : class show_subcategory work well and i can display subcategories under categories
>
> but class show_product  dont work and i can't display products under
>   subcategories .. the view dont show any errors and dont display
>   products
>
> i can't know where is my error in model relation or in controller class or in view

Comment: Can you also post your table schemas?

Comment: very thanks amit for your quickly answer .. i have updated my answer with all migrations table

Comment: I don't understand why in your `show_product()` function you are querying `Product` but saving it in `$subcategories` variable. Is it intentional?

Comment: dear amit . i can change it to  $products = Product::where and also change my view to  @foreach ($products as $product) but still get nothing